# Skip execution of a plugin based on a property

Tags: maven

In my Maven build I use `maven-processor-plugin` to generate JPA meta model like this

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            ....
        </execution>
</plugin>
```

Now I would like to skip the meta model generation based on a property, like this

```
$ mvn -Dspeed.up.build.from.eclipse=true
```

Unfortunately the `maven-processor-plugin` doesn't support `<skip>${speed.up.build.from.eclipse}</skip>` configuration tag like some plugins do.

I could put my plugin in a profile and then activate it based on my property. But then I need somehow to negate the value of the property...

So I need:

- Execute plugin, if no property was set
- Skip execution of the plugin, if the property was set

Is there some nice way to archieve it? If yes, how?

Comment: Is extending the plugin to support the `<skip>` tag an option? you could get the source code for the mojo, change it, then deploy it to an internal repository or back to maven central or wherever it's hosted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the [documentation](http://bsorrentino.github.io/maven-annotation-plugin/site3/process-mojo.html), there is indeed no `skip` property.

In such a case, a possible solution is to use the hack of setting the phase to `none` to disable the plugin execution. You would define 2 [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

- one activated [by the presence of the property](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html#profiles-sect-activation-config) `speed.up.build.from.eclipse` that would set a custom property `maven-annotation-plugin.phase` to `none`;
- one activated [by the absence of that property](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html#profiles-sect-activation-by-absence) that would set this custom property to the actual phase you want the plugin to run.

You would then use the custom property as your phase in your plugin configuration.

Note that it is a hack because this is an undocumented feature.

---

Another solution (that I would recommend actually) would be to make a pull request adding that feature. [The code is hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-annotation-plugin) so you can easily fork it, patch it and make a pull request. In the mean time, you can use your custom plugin, and when the request is merged, you could drop your custom plugin.

Comment: Profile trick worked! Thank you. I also added the proposal to add myself the skip option: https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-annotation-plugin/issues/59 No reaction yet.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue with a different plugin, I opted for the following solution:

```
<properties>
  <mvn.processor.goal>process</mvn.processor.goal>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>${mvn.processor.goal}</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            ....
        </execution>
</plugin>
```

Then when you run it you can do:

```
$ mvn -Dmvn.processor.goal=none
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. I use it a lot in the combination with profiles.